# Clarification about VLQ flags and Low Quality Posts queue

Tags: discussion

After reviewing the Low Quality Posts (LQP) queue for some time, I started believing that there is a direct connection between that queue and VLQ flags. The reason is that not all posts in the LQP queue are strictly "very low quality" as in exceptionally short, code-only, link-only or NAA.

For example some of them are sort of reasonable but are also the 35th answer to a famous question, or copy-pasted content or simply wrong answers.

So unless the background bots are much more sophisticated than I thought, there is probably a connection between VLQ/NAA flags and this queue. Which would make sense.

Moreover, I think it's okay to hit Delete / Recommend Deletion in the LQP on low-effort content that doesn't add anything new to the question. I'm fairy confident that many think the same, because I frequently go back in the review to see what option others chose, and this kind of content does meet deletion.
So it's even more reasonable that the community be able to flag such posts to send them into the review queue.

However it seems instead that VLQ flags (maybe NAA too) go straight to a diamond moderator queue, since some times they get declined with *"flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"*.

So my question is:

- do VLQ flags actually go into a diamond queue?
- what's the correct way (if any) to signal low-effort no-value-added answers that don't meet the requirements for strict VLQ flags?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The review posts in Low Quality Posts (LQP) queue come from 3 different sources:

- **NAA flags**
  Whenever any user uses "not an answer" flag the post will be added to the LQP by a batch job that runs very frequently. These flags are raised by users, but they are also raised by some of the userland bots. The flag will not be handled unless the review ends, or a mod handles the flag. When a mod handles the flag, the review item is immediately invalidated.
- **VLQ flags**
  These flags are almost the same as NAA flags. They also go into the mod queue in the same way. The only difference is that if an edit is made to the post after the flag is raised, the flag is marked as helpful and the review item is invalidated.
- **Automatic VLQ flags**
  The system automatically puts some answers into the LQP queue. These are not available to moderators. The exact criteria haven't been made public but the list of reasons can be found in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality).

For more information see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/515960

The queue is called **Low Quality** Posts, but the flags NAA/VLQ are meant only for **Very Low Quality** Posts. The review queue is meant to decide what to do with the posts that get there, but if you raise a flag, you should raise it only on posts requiring deletion for obvious reasons. If you raise such a flag on a low-quality post, which looks like an attempt at answering the question, your flag will be disputed or even declined.

Low-quality posts are meant to be downvoted, not deleted. We allow some leniency in the LQP queue but do not abuse it. One-liners, answers without explanation or wrong answers do not deserve to be deleted by reviewers. We rely on reviewers to make the right decision whether to keep the post with or without editing, or delete it for its appalling quality. However, if there is a dispute then mods will step in.

So, to answer your question *"what's the correct way (if any) to signal low-effort no-value-added answers that don't meet the requirements for strict VLQ flags?":*
**Down vote the answer!** If you have a good reason why the answer is worsening the quality of Stack Overflow, use a custom moderator flag and explain your reasoning for the post requiring a deletion.

Comment: "Down vote the answer" is the canonical, official answer to my question but we all know that low-rep reviewers don't downvote, because if they did they would have to keep gaining rep basically *in order to* downvote, given the endless stream of LQ content.  Moreover, are you sure you want the 35th reply to "How to convert an int to string in Javascript" to linger there with -5 downvotes? At that point it's just noise

Comment: @blackgreen If the new answer repeats exactly the same solution then you can raise a mod flag and point to the existing answer. Mods delete duplicate answers all the time. Make sure that the newly posted solution is **exactly** the same as the already existing one.

Comment: @blackgreen As for the reputation going down, don't worry about it too much. This is exactly why you earn the reputation point for. Ideally, downvoting shouldn't cost any reputation points, but it is a protective measure from abuse. One upvote gives you 10 downvotes, which is a pretty good exchange rate. Also, if the post gets deleted then you get your reputation back, so downvote VLQ posts in addition to flagging them